# Visibility rules if field is filled in

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, blocks

We made a visibility rule to display a field when a second field has been filled, and display another field when the second field is empty.
It works well, but since we updated Ctools and some Drupal modules, it gives false output.

What I did is:

- Adding a field with a visibility rule to display the field based on another field value
  (I left the value empty to display the field when it is empty.)
- Duplicating that field, and adding the same visibility rule, for which I then selected "Reverse" to display the field when it contains any value

The problem is that the visibility rule doesn't apply for the case when the field is empty, but it works well when the field is not empty, even if I disabled the second rule.

How does the plugin (for the visibility rule) know about empty and non empty fields?

I know that it could be solved with PHP code, but I need to know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys the problem wasn't caused by visibility rules.

We found an issue with image actions module update not ctools

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is the difference between if `field['und][0]['value']` is set or not. Even if `field['und][0]['value']` is empty, it's different with not instancied field.

Try a default value on this field and add an other visibility condition on this default value